# Using Tiled .tmx files in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: dictionary, xna, editor, tmx

I've downloaded Griddy2D but can't seem to figure out how to use it. If possible, a step-by-step walkthrough on how to take a .tmx and load it into XNA would be ideal.

Comment: _[Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, **tutorial** or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_

Comment: Need to learn xml serialization and copy the model from the tmx file. Your question is too vague to answer specifically what your problem is.